# CRM 2011-Business Logic error

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, crm

I am working in CRM 2011.
When my collegue update a field and save.Error is showing as                                                                                'Business process error
An error occurred in the plug-in'
But same filed when i tried no issue.[Tried many times]

What could be the reason for such an error only for that person.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Seems that you have plugin that handles update. To remove error deactivate plugin and provide code for investigation.

Answer (score 0):

This is 2 directional troubleshooting..

1. Debug the plugin, or see the trace message for exact error.
2. Check the difference between your user profile & your colleague for differences in security role, BU, Team, etc